PHP Tesseract OCR empty result
I am new to Tesseract OCR, and I want to scrape data from this statement image using PHP and shell_exec.
tesseract "D:/page_2.png" "D:/page_2.txt" -l eng

But the result is empty.
I want the output to be json like this
{
    "norek": "046-1943-828",
    "nama": "ANUGERAH RUTH ANGG",
    "mutasi": [
        {
            "tgl": "01\/06",
            "ket": "3105\/FTSCY\/WS95271 3300000.00LAMBERTO FREDRICKN TRSF E-BANKING CR",
            "total": "3,300,000",
            "tipe": "CR"
        },
        {
            "tgl": "02\/06",
            "ket": "0206\/FTSCY\/WS95031 150000.00babi kecap GALUH RATNA YUNIAT TRSF E-BANKING DB",
            "total": "150,000",
            "tipe": "DB"
        }
    ]
}

Has anyone experienced this?
